# Code Blocks is not working from every folder on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, code-blocks

I've recently installed Code::Blocks on my ubuntu 18.04 from Ubuntu store.

> It's version 16.01+dfsg-2.1

Now It compiles and runs c/c++ smoothly but only on outside folders like

```
Documents
Downloads
Music
Pictures
Videos
```

But when I try to save/open a c/c++ file in a folder like -

> Home/Documents/Practise/cc++

The file is not saved/I cannot open an existing c/c++ file.
[image]

But it works fine if I save/open the c/c++ file in -

> Home/Documents/Practise/

How can I make the IDE workable in any directory?

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted out the problem. 
My inner folder structure was -

```
Home/Documents/Practise/cc++
```

but the folder **cc++** was named by **c\c++** but the codeblocks takes it as cc++ (see screenshot).
I've **renamed** it to c++ now it **works fine**.